# What is the relationship between pressure and concentration in liquids in porous media?

Tags: pressure, boundary-conditions, porous-media

I am working on a model in porous media. In particular, it is about the formation damage due to the precipitation. I assigned Dirichlet boundary condition for the concentration near the well-bore, which decreases as time passes. I think this decrease is because also the pressure decreases as precipitation happens.
My question is how can I relate the concentration to the pressure? I know the relationship for ideal gases, p = cRT, but it is not my case.

Comment: Please be more specific.  Is this problem associated with drilling a natural gas or oil well?

Comment: The problem is about production wells that produce oil, gas or geothermal fluids. My focus is on the calcite precipitation on geothermal wells. If the concentration of the calcium ions is higher than the equilibrium concentration, then precipitation happens and it decreases the porosity which affects the production rate. I am modelling this precipitation process, but I am not sure how to impose boundary conditions at the wellbore.